# Access point Netgear WAX610 Ethernet not working at 2.5Gbps

Tags: access-point, gigabit-ethernet

I've just bought a Netgear WAX610 (https://www.netgear.com/support/product/wax610.aspx) access point. Though it is advertised as coming with a 2.5Gbps Ethernet port, the port actually is working only at 1Gbps.

The access point is attached to a Netgear XS716T switch with a tested CAT6A cable.

The 1Gbps is confirmed on both the access point's side (LAN led in solid amber, see https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WAX610/WAX610_IG_EN.pdf) and on the switch's web interface.

Any thoughts what could I try?

Answer (score 1):

The switch you named only supports 10G, 1G and 100M speeds on its switch ports, according to its [datasheet](https://www.netgear.com/images/datasheet/switches/SmartSwitches/XS708T_XS712Tv2_XS716T_XS728T_XS748T_DS.pdf). 2.5G and 5G are not supported.

You should purchase a switch which supports 2.5G and/or 5G speeds.